# SPARX Enterprise Architect DDL template language

Tags: templates, ddl, enterprise-architect

I would like to ask about DDL templates in EA. I need to tweak the template for generating the tables.

The following code should be self-explainatory about what I want to do...

```
$PARTITION_BY = %classTag:"PARTITION_BY"%
$PARTITION_TARGET = %classTag:"PARTITION_TARGET"%


%if $PARTITION_BY == "RANGE"%
PARTITION BY RANGE ($PARTITION_TARGET) INTERVAL(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH'))
  (
    PARTITION "P_2016Q4" VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2017-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')) TABLESPACE BA_DATA
  )
%endIf%
```

There will be more variations of Partitions based on value of `$PARTITION_BY` values once I get it work and basically serves as a crossroad. `$PARTITION_TARGET` then contains the FK or column that should the table be partitioned by... However...

What I get as a generated result is

```
%if
PARTITION BY RANGE ()
TABLESPACE BA_DATA
```

Which is like totally wrong.

First, why is there the `%if` part when the IF statement is written exactly like the others (and no endIf counterpart).

Secondly, both `$PARTITION_BY` and `$PARTITION_TARGET` are empty. I suppose that is because of the classTag used should be something else, but EA does not know what tableTag is and I did not find a valid substitution.

Thirdly, since `$PARTITION_BY` is null, why the IF block even writes.

I am new to EA, so I welcome all tips in regards of how to tackle this issue.

Comment: I'd not go this proprietary "language" path and use the API to create the DDL. This is fairly easy and allows anything you need in terms of condition checking.

Comment: My employer wanted me to go this proprietary path. I ended up butchering other, expected, tags in the end and everyone is happy...

Comment: Yeah, "butcher" is the right word xD However, you should dig into automation anyway... You might answer your question by posting the results in an answer below.